# How do I replace new lines characters in CSV files downloaded using the Google sheets API?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, google-sheets, google-api-python-client, gspread

I'm using Python 3.9 and the Google Sheets SDK for Python v 3.6.0.  I want to download a Google sheet as a CSV and I would like to replace any new line characters that occur in the cell data with nothing.  I tried the below

```
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    sheet = client.open('ChiCommons_Directory')

    # get the third sheet of the Spreadsheet.  This
    # contains the data we want
    sheet_instance = sheet.get_worksheet(3)

    url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + sheet.id + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=' + str(sheet_instance.id)
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + client.auth.token}
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    output = re.sub(r'[\n\r]', '', res.text)
    print(output)
```

This doesn't seem to be replacing anything.  Specifically the line
output = re.sub(r'[\n\r]', '', res.text)
does not seem to be doing its job.  However, I only want to replace new lines in teh cell data, not the new lines that divide each row of data.  Not sure the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to replace the line breaks in each cell.
- You don't want to replace the line breaks for each row in the CSV data.

#### Modification points:

- When I tested your script, the line breaks for each row are also removed. So, in this case, I would like to propose the following flow.

  1. Parse the CSV data and convert it to a list.
  2. Remove the line breaks in each cell.
  3. Convert the list to the CSV data.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
output = re.sub(r'[\n\r]', '', res.text)
print(output)
```

To:

```
ar = csv.reader(io.StringIO(res.text, newline=""))
output = "\n".join([",".join(map(str, ['"' + c.replace('\n', '') + '"' for c in r])) for r in ar])
# or, output = "\n".join([",".join(map(str, ['"' + re.sub(r'[\n\r]', '', c) + '"' for c in r])) for r in ar])
print(output)
```

- In this case, please use `import csv` and `import io`.
- If you don't want to add `"` for each cell, please modify as follows.

  ```
    output = "\n".join([",".join(map(str, [c.replace('\n', '') for c in r])) for r in ar])
  ```